how to upload a folder
How to upload a full folder with sub folders into an existing project in a tex editor such as overleaf?
Overleaf has the feature to create folders in an existing project. But it doesn't have an upload option to upload a full folder (even as a zip).
Similar question question has been asked before and marked as off topic. However it is gap in a commonly available tex editor such as overleaf. Further 1988 of questions have been tagged under 'overleaf'
How can one adds either an external folder or a chpater to an existing project (as it is or as a zip)?
This can also enable downloading separate folders or chapters of a project.
I am guessing this is a reproducable version of the issue in any text editor for that matter. Free version itself allows creation of a project and its basic features stated in this question. Otherwise open to comments and suggestions to improve the question.

Just because a tag exists and is used doesn't necessarily mean that it's on topic.  The problem with the overleaf tag is that people use the tag because they're using Overleaf, but if their problem isn't specific to Overleaf, then it's not the appropriate tag.  In this case, Overleaf is an appropriate tag (but not latex3).  Unfortunately, this will still probably be closed, because it's really a question for Overleaf support, not TeX.SE.  (On the other hand, there are Overleaf support staff that keep an eye on this site, so they may chime in.)

that said, uploading a folder works fine for me. what problem do you encounter exactly?

Overleaf-specific questions should be addressed to the Overleaf Helpdesk. Their LaTeX support staff are top-notch.


Open the project you want to upload the directory to.
On the left hand side, you have a list of folders and files already in the project. At the top, there's a drop-down menu shown as three vertical dots. Click and choose Upload.
A dialogue box appears telling you you can upload files or select a folder. There are two links: one to select files and one to select a folder. Click the one which lets you select a folder.
Your OS's or browser's file selection dialogue will appear. Navigate to the directory you want to upload, select it and press open/upload or however the button appears.
You may now be asked to confirm that you really want to do this. (I think this is probably a browser feature rather than Overleaf - hence the 'may'.) Click continue.
The directory with all contents will be uploaded and added to the project.

This also works recursively. That is, I uploaded a directory containing sub-directories and everything was uploaded and the structure maintained.

However, Overleaf does not recognise most of the files I uploaded as tex files. This has nothing to do with their being uploaded as the contents of a directory, though. It just doesn't recognise many tex file extensions. (Interestingly, it does recognise .lua, which can't be compiled with tex, while it refuses to show any content for the files which can be compiled with it.)

Out of curiosity: does this also hold when uploading and extracting compressed files?

@MS-SPO sorry. I only tried out of curiosity. if you know you can upload and extract compressed files, you're already ahead of me ;).

Just remembering a kind of standard trick from my former colleagues in support ... ;)

@MS-SPO if I upload a .zip, it stays a .zip. what did you do to upload and extract exactly?

Zip a number of .tex files, upload and extract. It’s a different way to upload any number and hierarchy of files.

@MS-SPO i couldn't figure out how to extract.

Yeah, tricky: uploading AND trying to unzip isn't provided, as it seems. However ... NewProject / UploadProject, drag zip file there. https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=i22sF369bqA&t=21 . It expects a complete project, but probably you can treat even fragments this way and move interesting files to your main project. (Well, perhaps not ... or not that easily ... So have identity between zip file and relevant .tex files, i.e. project)

@MS-SPO ah, ok. yes, I didn't try that. I only looked inside an already-created project.

Found myself in the same trap. Don't worry. Bye for now
